# Replace string between two char(special symbol) in php

Tags: php, string, substring

I have a string like: He `*is*` a good boy. How `*are*` you. Then I want to replace **is** and **are** with input type **textbox** means replace things between asterisk(*). How can I get this Please help me out.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. -1

Comment: I have less knowledge of preg_replace.

Comment: Dear downvoter let me why are you downvote for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $buffer = 'He *is* a good boy. How *are* you.';
    echo "Before: $buffer<br />";
    $buffer = preg_replace_callback('/(\*(.*?)\*)/s', 'compute_replacement', $buffer);
    echo "After: $buffer<br />";

    function compute_replacement($groups) {
        // $groups[1]: *item*
        // $groups[2]: item
        return '<input type="text" value="'.$groups[2].'" />';
    }
?>
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Its working fine. thanks mate. But preg_replace_callback this function is not working in my file I replace with preg_replace.

Comment: This astonishes me - the function _preg\_replace\_callback_ has been around since PHP version 4. But, I'm glad you found a solution that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
<?php
$x="hai, *was/is* are you, is this *was* test ";
echo preg_replace("/\*[\w\/]*\*/","",$x);
?>
```

Comment: In my question is and are is example I want to replace string between asterix. @rogin thomas

Comment: It's replacing only one.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php); e.g:

```
<?php

$pattern = '/\*\w+\*/';
$string  = 'he *is* a good boy';
$replacement = 'was';

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Yields:

> he was a good boy

Comment: Upvoted for using a pattern that will match anything between asterix !

Comment: If he *is/are* a good boy then it will not working. @Darragh Enright

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:

```
$txt = "He *is* a good boy. How *are* you.";
$_GET['one'] = "doesn't";
$_GET['two'] = "think about";

preg_match_all( '{\*[^*]+\*}',$txt,$matches );
$txt = str_replace( $matches[0][0], $_GET['one'], $txt );
$txt = str_replace( $matches[0][1], $_GET['two'], $txt );

echo $txt;
```

<kbd>**[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/ZOQMb)**</kbd>

or, with `preg_replace`, in this way:

```
$txt = preg_replace
(
    '/^(.*)\*[^*]+\*(.*)\*[^*]+\*(.*)$/',                  # <-- (Edited)
    "\\1{$_GET[one]}\\2{$_GET[two]}\\3", 
    $txt 
);
```